# Jenkins throws Buildlog error while running using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2, jenkins-groovy

I run a pipeline using Jenkins scripts written using DSL commands. The problem arise when suddenly one of the stages fail unpredictably with the following error:

```
Failed to parse D:\newjenkins\jobs\JOB_NAME\builds\166\changelog1.xml
```

The script I use is as follows:

```groovy
pipeline{
   agent none
   parameters{
    ...
   }
    stages('Execution Started'){
    stage('Checkout'){
        parallel{
            stage('Checkout machine1'){
                agent{
                    label "machine1"
                }
                when{
                    beforeAgent true
                    expression { return params.MODULE == 'ALL' || params.MODULE == 'Checkout'}  
                }
                steps{
                    echo "machine1"
                    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: '44522e30-239d-4b35-bf11-41f02778026f', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: 'location_checkout_1', remote: 'url_checkout_1'], [credentialsId: '44522e30-239d-4b35-bf11-41f02778026f', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: 'location_checkout', remote: 'url_checkout']], quietOperation: false, workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])
                }      
            }
            stage('Checkout machine2'){
                agent{
                    label "machine2"
                }
                when{
                    beforeAgent true
                    expression { return params.MODULE == 'ALL' || params.MODULE == 'Checkout'}  
                }
                steps{
                    echo "machine2"
                    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: '44522e30-239d-4b35-bf11-41f02778026f', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: 'location_checkout_1', remote: 'url_checkout_1'], [credentialsId: '44522e30-239d-4b35-bf11-41f02778026f', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: 'location_checkout', remote: 'url_checkout']], quietOperation: false, workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])
                }      
            }
            stage('Checkout machine3'){
                agent{
                    label "machine3"
                }
                when{
                    beforeAgent true
                    expression { return params.MODULE == 'ALL' || params.MODULE == 'Checkout'}  
                }
                steps{
                    echo "machine3"
                    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: '44522e30-239d-4b35-bf11-41f02778026f', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: 'location_checkout_1', remote: 'url_checkout_1'], [credentialsId: '44522e30-239d-4b35-bf11-41f02778026f', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: 'location_checkout', remote: 'url_checkout']], quietOperation: false, workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])
                }      
            }
        }
    }
}
        stage('Build'){
        parallel{
            stage('Build at machine1'){
                agent{
                    label "machine1"
                }
                when{
                    beforeAgent true
                    expression { return params.MODULE == 'ALL' || params.MODULE == 'Checkout' || params.MODULE == 'Build'}  
                }
                steps{
                    echo "machine1"
                    bat 'cd location_machine && ant main '
                }        
            }
            stage('Build at machine2'){
                agent{
                    label "machine2"
                }
                when{
                    beforeAgent true
                    expression { return params.MODULE == 'ALL' || params.MODULE == 'Checkout' || params.MODULE == 'Build'}  
                }
                steps{
                    echo "machine2"
                    bat 'cd location_machine && ant main '
                }        
            }
            stage('Build at machine3'){
                agent{
                    label "machine3"
                }
                when{
                    beforeAgent true
                    expression { return params.MODULE == 'ALL' || params.MODULE == 'Checkout' || params.MODULE == 'Build'}  
                }
                steps{
                    echo "machine3"
                    bat 'cd location_machine && ant main '
                }        
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

This is a sample script I use. This tends to throw the error highlighted above.
[image: Jenkins issue]
I mostly set the mode of checking out scripts to "svn update as much as possible " but it does not solve anything. Why does this fail? What are the possible ways to avoid this issue?

Edit:
The checkout for pipeline I am using is:-
[image: Checkout groovy script for execution]

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is open issue around this [Exceptions by parallel SCM checkout](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34313). Most likely the issue is with Jenkins Pipeline plugins itself. I am not sure if this will solve the problem from but looking at one of the comments on open bug you can try [Resource lock](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/#lock-lock-shared-resource)

Comment: Using sleep is a sort of a workaround the issue. However using "sleep 5 seconds" works in one script while in the other case it keeps throwing a **WorkflowScript: 59: Not a valid stage section definition: "sleep 7 SECONDS"** error